# What other ways than IP tracking can we stop users from registering multiple accounts

Tags: php

I am building a classified website, which is 'free' per-se. To list it is free, but once sold we take a % off the final value like ebay. Now, we add the total and give the user an invoice each month, but if they decide not to pay we disable their account...

Now, my problem is they could just create another account and bypass the fees, I will be tracking IP's and only allow 1 account per person. But they could simply enter ranom information, what other ways can I track the user from creating multiple accounts?

- IP
- Their Browsers cookie (even though they can delete, some non-techy people will strugle)
- ??
- ??

I didn't know where to ask this question other than here.

Comment: Email address & phone number verification (2 Factor auth) are usually harnessed in these situations. And on "extreme" levels, proof of identity documents as Paypal does

Comment: request a valid email-adress.

Comment: Valid emails can be created in a minute, not good enough in my opinion

Comment: Many connections change the IP every 24h or even on every dial in. Then another user gets assigned a possibly banned IP.

Comment: Take an advanced deposit

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a wide range of methods to be sure that a user is who he/she says he/she is. However, you can never be completely sure.

A few methods:

- Log IP Addresses
- Verify the email adress
- Verify the Phone number by sending a text or giving a call supplying some kind of code
- Verifying the address - requiring unique and existing home addresses
- Verifying the passport/identification
- Verifying the bank account number by transfering a small amount of money and asking the customer what amount they have received

Of course these methods can be combined to make your system as close to full proof as possible.